# boost::multiprecision compare two cpp_int values

Tags: c++, boost, compare

How can I compare two cpp_int values like

```
boost::multipercision::uint256_t x = 100;
boost::multipercision::uint256_t y = 50;
if (x > y){
std::cout << "X is bigger than Y" <<endl;
} else {
std::cout << "Y is bigger than X" <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors in your code.

`boost::multiprecision` is not spelled `boost::multipercision`.

Also, your if-else block should include a check for `x == y`, since in your code, it'll simply output `Y is bigger than X` when x and y are the same.